# Que hace la constante auto en realidad en css?

Tags: html, css

Para establecer bien mi pregunta, pondré el siguiente código de ejemplo :

```css
.parent_element
{
    position:relative;
    display :inline-block;
    background-color : #0f0;
    padding : 20px;
    left : 20%;
    top : 40%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow : hidden;
}
.parent_element > .son_element
{
    background-color: rgb(36, 124, 36);
    padding : 20px;
    height : 100px;
    color : #fff;
    border-radius : 10px;
    transition-property: height ;
    transition-duration : 1s;
}
.parent_element:hover > .son_element
{
    height : 900px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "parent_element">
        <div class="son_element">
            Hola
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

En este caso, al hacerle el `hover` al `.parent_element` el elemento hijo crece lentamente precisamente por que se esta controlando la velocidad con `transition-property`, sin embargo, cuando se establece como valor inicial `height : auto` al `.son_element`, por alguna razón el `transition-property` deja de surtir efecto, *a que se debe esto?*

Comment: el valor `auto` establece un valor *automático* que en `height` se traduce a ocupar el espacio suficiente para que el contenido alcance.

Comment: Que es lo que genera que el transition no aplique cuando el height es auto?

Comment: En el titulo tenes una pregunta, que te respondieron un comentario mas arriba. En "la pregunta" propiamente dicha, al final, haces otra pregunta (lindo trabalenguas jaja). Las transiciones se aplican sobre ciertas propiedades, y sobre otras no. En lugar de usar ``height:auto``  te aconsejo que uses ``max-height`` ya que esta útima si responde a la propiedad ``transition``. No vas a poder darle el valor ``auto``, pero podes darle alguna calculada  o valor fijo

Comment: @AgustinG. la propiedad height si responde a transition, de hecho lo uso en el ejemplo que pongo en la pregunta. Deja de responder cuando uso auto